# how to get data from one mysql table to html echo from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have one php which creates list of stuff in page from one database table and i have another table which have all stored rating in it and i need to get those rating to that stuff list. both tables are sorted differently, but both have same collumn called id so i guess i can somehow align those rating to fit where it belongs.

php which gets rating:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *,CAST((user_votes+visitor_votes)/(user_voters+visitor_voters) AS BINARY(4)) AS total FROM wp_gdsr_data_article");;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['total'];?></br><?php
  }
```

php which creates the stuff list:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * , DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE, founded ) as date_difference FROM business");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 ?><li class="onebusiness <?php echo $row['category'];?> <?php echo $row['status'];?>"><a href="<?php
  echo $row['link'];?>"><img src="<?php
  echo $row['img'];?>" /><p class="name"><?php
  echo $row['name'];?></p></a><p class="age">Age: <?php
  echo $row['date_difference']?> days</p><span class="status<?php
  echo $row['status']?>"></span></li><?php
  }
```

Comment: It's called using a `JOIN`. Please stop using `mysql_` functions; they are deprecated.

Comment: ok thanks and what should i use instead mysql_ ???

Comment: Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table2.column FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.id = table1.id
```